# Проблема с адаптивной версткой сайта, высота

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Делаю адаптивную верстку сайта, на телефоне оказывается, что высота девайса меньше высоты окна браузера, и часть сайта не видна под блоком браузера (можно увидеть на фото). Как сделать чтобы высота сайта была равной высоте окна браузера?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял по изображению - у Вас боковая прокрутка, проверьте все элементы которые могут иметь фиксированную ширину. А в идеале дайте ссылку, потому что суть вопроса не совсем ясна по фото.

Comment: https://billiard-bc9c1.web.app/ , Часть навигации внизу не видна, все размеры указывал по высоте как 100vh